# Adding jQuery plugin to angular app

Tags: angular, jquery-plugins, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Frameworks used

1. Angular: 5.2.3
2. Foundation(Zurb): 6.2.4

Created an angular app using

```
> ng new foundation-plugin-app --style=sass
> cd foundation-plugin-app
> npm install foundation-sites --save
```

Everything work as expected till this.
Then I added [foundation-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-datepicker)

```
> npm install foundation-datepicker --save
```

This is how the plugin is initialized.

```
$('#scenario_start_date').fdatepicker({
  initialDate: '02-12-1989',
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
  disableDblClickSelection: true,
  leftArrow: '<<',
  rightArrow: '>>',
  closeIcon: 'X',
  closeButton: true
});
```

Now, to make it work, followed these steps
1.Added `styleUrls` in `app.component.ts`

```
styleUrls: [
    // ...,
    '../../node_modules/foundation-datepicker/scss/foundation-datepicker.scss'    ]
```

2.Added `scripts` in `angular-cli.json`

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/foundation-datepicker/js/foundation-datepicker.js"
]
```

3.Added `typings` to `app.component.ts`

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

and imported `jquery` and `foundation-datepicker` plugin to the page

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'foundation-datepicker';
```

4.Lastly, called the plugin in `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts`

```
$('#scenario_start_date').fdatepicker(/*...*/);
```

Which gave error as

> `fdatepicker` is not defined.
>   So I type-casted it as

```
(<any>$('#scenario_start_date')).fdatepicker(/*...*/);
```

to suppress the error.

This gives a new error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
>
> at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../foundation-datepicker/js/foundation-datepicker.min.js:1)
>     at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../foundation-datepicker/js/foundation-datepicker.min.js:1)
>     at Object.../../../../foundation-datepicker/js/foundation-datepicker.min.js (vendor.bundle.js:36)
>     at __ webpack_require __ (inline.bundle.js:55)
>     at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/app.component.ts:15)
>     at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.component.ts (main.bundle.js:21)
>     at __ webpack_require __ (inline.bundle.js:55)
>     at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts:11)
>     at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:29)
>     at __ webpack_require __ (inline.bundle.js:55)

What am I doing wrong with the code? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I think you've forgotten to include `JQuery.js` to `angular-cli.json`.

Comment: @abbas amiri: no. It's added as a dependency. Foundation needs it. Also $("#scenario_start_date") is working when I `console.log` it.

Comment: well, I did exactly what you did, except I added `jquery` and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your import statement seems to be wrong.

Please try `import $ from 'jquery';`

And make sure that jQuery is bundled with your generated bundle file.

In your case it is either not globally exported or not included in the window context.

In this case try

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: Why would this not be an answer? jQuery is undefined in his case because his import is wrong.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me but this solution worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50020329/89605

Comment: This is TypeScript related and a different problem imo.