# Using jquery plugin with Angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm using trying to use the following datepicker in my Angular 5 project but I'm not sure how to import it:-

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#

I'm using Angular CLI to build my project and I've added the bootstrap-datepicker.min.js file into my scripts section in my angular-cli.json file:-

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../js/custom.js",
    "../js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"
  ]
```

And I've also imported JQuery into my Angular component:-

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

..which does work as I can reference the $ object in my component and get a handle to a load of JQuery functions. However, when I do something like:-

```
$("dateField").datepicker()
```

It tells me the function is not available on the JQuery object. Does anyone have any ideas how to use this in Angular?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: have you installed jquery types ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Try that

```
declare let $: any;
```

On a side note, don't use jQuery if you don't absolutely need it. There are plenty of angular calendar available, and ng-bootstrap is a native angular library providing bootstrap components, instead of bootstrap.js

Comment: This did do the trick as I now have the datepicker function but I can't seem to get it to set up the control as a datepicker! Ah well another problem

Comment: Your `datefield` selector may not be valid?

Comment: I've rolled back my changes but yes it might be because I was doing $('datefield') rather than $('#datefield') so I'll try that when I get some time

Comment: Thanks @David. This worked. Can you please explain why using `declare` works but not `import`?

Comment: @burnt1ce I think that if you use `import`, it'll import the basic jquery module to `$`, hence erasing the plugin's code also imported into `$`